# Изменение кодировки списков Python

Tags: python

Час добрый
Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно переделать следующий список в кодировке cp1252 для сохранения в файл используя utf-8

```py
full_info.append(
    {
        'title': title_list[0],
        'about_profile': about_profile_list[0],
        'video_links': all_video_links[append_number],
        'video_data': video_data_list[append_number],
        'video_desc': video_descriptions_list[append_number]
    }
)
```

На данный момент если сохраняю при помощи

```py
with open('data_file.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for link in full_info:
        writer.writerow([link['title'], link['about_profile'], link['video_links'], link['video_data'], link['video_desc']])
```

На каком-то моменте вылазит ошибка декодирования, о том, что невозможно декодировать элемент при помощи cp1252, если сохранять в файл без encoding='utf-8'. 
Исправил пост, пробовал переводить из cp1252 в utf-8 следующим способом:

```py
full_info.append(
    {
        'title': title_list[0].encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8'),
        'about_profile': about_profile_list[0].encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8'),
        'video_links': all_video_links[append_number].encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8'),
        'video_data': video_data_list[append_number].encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8'),
        'video_desc': video_descriptions_list[append_number].encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')
    }
)
```

Но во время декодирования вылетает

```
  File "C:\Users\kk\Desktop\ytb_scrapper\main.py", line 200, in get_videos_link
    'title': title_list[0].encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8'),
  File "C:\Users\kk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555335/how-to-convert-a-string-from-cp-1251-to-utf-8

Comment: Пробовал, сейчас обновлю пост чтобы объяснить. Подождите пару минут

Comment: `На каком-то моменте` - так Вы определите, на каком. А там уже и ясно будет, почему не записывается.

Comment: @MikhailMurugov Т.к. собираю описание ютуб роликов, то скорее всего не может обработать различные смайлики или спец.символы по типу ↑♪♥►♦•◘